# Is there a valid way of defining a variable within the condition statement of a conditional(if) structure?

Tags: javascript, scope, variable-declaration

Is there a condensed way of defining a variable within the condition of an if statement in JavaScript? For example:

```
var arr = [1,2,3];
console.log(len); // output is null, since it was never declared
if ((var len = arr.length) > 0) { // len  == 3
    // logic using variable 'len ' here
}
```

Or is the only way around this to declare and assign the value of `len` before the conditional statement?

Comment: Why not using only `arr.lenght` in the conditional statement and then declare the variable `len` inside of it?

Comment: That would make it a line longer, I'm just trying to see if there is a condensed way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your concern is the number of lines you write, you can declare len in the same line where you declare arr such as:

```
var len, arr = [1,2,3];
console.log(len); 
if ((len = arr.length) > 0) { // len  == 3
    // logic using variable 'len ' here

    console.log(len); 
}
```

I personally avoid setting values in conditionals. Conditionals are no place to set variables. It looks like an error, it leads to errors and people that read your code will be likely to miss that a variable is being set in the conditional statement.

Good luck!

Comment: @rageandqq your code doesn't work, the variable must be declared outside the condition.  It can be assigned in the condition though.  I would advise against this because it often looks like an accident and that it should be `==` or `===`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment from @VictorJohnson in the other answer, I would declare my variables like below

```
var arr = [1,2,3], len=arr.length;
console.log(len);             // len == 3
if (len > 0) {
    // logic using variable 'len ' here

    console.log(len); 
}
```

This removes the possible confusion of the `if` block and remains quite condensed